# Wiremock request.query not working with a paramter that contains dots

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

I'm using sprint-boot with wiremock-jre8, what i'm trying to to is to get a value from URL params, but this value contains dots "product.productCharacteristic.value"

```
{
    "request": {
        "urlPath": "/exampleOfPath",
        "method": "GET",
        "queryParameters": {
            "product.productCharacteristic.name": {
                "equalTo": "MSISDN"
            },
            "product.productCharacteristic.value": {
                "matches": ".*"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
            "key": "the value should be here {{request.query['product.productCharacteristic.value']}}"
        },
        "transformers": [
            "response-template"
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

i have tested all of those

- {{request.query.['product.productCharacteristic.value']}}
- {{request.query['product.productCharacteristic.value']}}
- {{request.query['product%2EproductCharacteristic%2Evalue']}}
- {{request.query.['product%2EproductCharacteristic%2Evalue']}}
- {{request.query.product%2EproductCharacteristic%2Evalue}}
- {{request.query.product.productCharacteristic.value}}
- {{lookup request.query 'product.productCharacteristic.value'}}
- {{lookup request.query 'product%2EproductCharacteristic%2Evalue'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this format:
`{{request.query.[product.productCharacteristic.value]}}`

See [WireMock - Response Templating - The request model](https://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#:%7E:text=1%5D%7D%7D%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,The%20request%20model,-The%20model%20of):

> `request.headers.[<key>]` - Header with awkward characters e.g. `request.headers.[$?blah]`

Comment: worked, so the quotes was the problem